# EE3 Transcribe url not updating after language switch

Tags: transcribe

After language switch from news entry, url goes from `localhost/news/reach-and-read` to `localhost/es/news/alcance-y-lea`

I was expecting change to `localhost/es/noticias/alcance-y-lea`

But if I change from news page `localhost/news/` it changes to `localhost/es/noticias/` works fine any ideas whats wrong with the entry url update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their latest update fixed 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Everything worked fine but now it doesn't work for me. According to example above, I translate "news" in Transcribe (Transcribe -> Templates) but when change the language I can't see any changes in URL.

In my case even the first segment is not translated.

I updated Transcribe to 2.2.1 version but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the translations for all the relevant templates in both languages.  I also found that I needed to translate the name for "index" for my templates.

I hope that helps.